# JHipster custom error message translation

Tags: angular, spring-boot, exception, jhipster

How can I translate custom error message in JHipster App with Angular UI?

I have added custom exception handler:

```
    @ExceptionHandler
    default ResponseEntity<Problem> handleSomeBusinessException(final SomeBusinessException exception, final NativeWebRequest request) {

        final Problem problem = Problem.builder()
            .withStatus(UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
            .with("BusinessException", SomeBusinessException .class.getName())
            .with("BusinessMessage", exception.getMessage())
            .build();

        return create(exception, problem, request);
    }
```

Next I modified *alert-error.component.ts*

```
  this.httpErrorListener = eventManager.subscribe('someApp.httpError', (response: JhiEventWithContent<HttpErrorResponse>) => {
      const httpErrorResponse = response.content;
      switch (httpErrorResponse.status) {

        case 422:
          this.addErrorAlert(httpErrorResponse.error.BusinessMessage);
          break;
```

Unfortunately when I run app and *SomeBusinessException* is thrown I see follwing stuff in UI:

> translation-not-found[Some business message related to
> SomeBusinessException]

Can you please advise where I can introduce translation of my *BusinessMessage*?

**Update:**
I have checked src\main\webapp\i18n\en\error.json but it is bound to http.code, not to message itself

Comment: You need to create a dedicated translation in the frontend json translation files. It should be in `src/main/webapp/i18n/en/error.json`

Comment: how can I specify that I wolud like to translate using BusinessMessage, not using http code? I have multiple business layer exceptions both having 422 code

Comment: You could use e.g. use the simple classname of your business exception as translation key instead of the code. From what I see the `BusinessMessage` is the exception message which might not be a good translation key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using simple name of exception. Additionally you can pass parameters, to be substituted by **ngx-translate**.

First of all you need to pass custom parameters within a **Problem**:

```
@ExceptionHandler
default ResponseEntity<Problem> handleSomeBusinessException(final SomeBusinessException exception, final NativeWebRequest request) {

    final Problem problem = Problem.builder()
        .withStatus(UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
        .with("businessException", SomeBusinessException.class.getSimpleName())
        .with("parameterKey", "some value goes here")
        .build();

    return create(exception, problem, request);
}
```

Second is constructor of **AlertErrorComponent**:

```
constructor(private alertService: JhiAlertService, private eventManager: JhiEventManager, translateService: TranslateService) {
...
     switch (httpErrorResponse.status) {
        ...
        case 422:
          this.addErrorAlert('', 'business.' + httpErrorResponse.error.businessException, httpErrorResponse.error);
          break;
```

Third is to provide translation with parameter (supported by **ngx-translate**):

*src/main/webapp/i18n/en/error.json*

```
{
  "business": {
    "SomeBusinessException ": "Translated text goes here. {{parameterKey}}",
  }
  ...
}
```

*{{parameterKey}}* will be substituted by **ngx-translate** with *"some value goes here"*

So you will see on screen following message:

> Translated text goes here. some value goes here

You can also check full source code [here](https://github.com/tillias/microservice-catalog/commit/840652633303285ee271e08f9302cf800b04d23f)

Comment: Thanks for putting the detailed answer here.